# I'm unable to solve this error in my SQL statement

Tags: sql

I want to use order by clause in join which I have written but it's showing an error and I am not able to solve this:

```
SELECT 
    products_details.*, master_category.title as cat1 
FROM  
    products_details 
JOIN 
    master_category ON products_details.product_category = master_category.id 
ORDER BY 
    products_details.product_name 
WHERE
    1 = 1 
    AND products_details.status != 2;
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: and how is this tagged to javascript,jquery,html and css?

Comment: Please Add the error log, which help us to solve the problem.

Comment: the `order by` clause does not go in the join

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.*, `mc`.`title` AS `cat1 FROM products_details pd INNER JOIN master_category mc' at line 2

SELECT * FROM `SELECT` `pd`.*, `mc`.`title` AS `cat1 FROM products_details pd INNER JOIN master_category mc ON pd`.`product_category = mc`.`id WHERE pd`.`status != 2 ORDER BY pd`.`product_name; ORDER BY product_name desc LIMIT 0`, 10

Comment: What is your SQL database (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.) ?

Answer (score 1):

`WHERE` comes before `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT
    pd.*,
    mc.title AS cat1 
FROM products_details pd
INNER JOIN master_category mc
    ON pd.product_category = mc.id
WHERE
    pd.status != 2
ORDER BY
    pd.product_name;
```

Also, I introduced *aliases* into your query for the tables, which leaves it easier to read.

Comment: Darn - beat me by **two** seconds! :-)

Comment: @marc_s Weird...it actually shows you beating me by 7 seconds.  But, I rewrote the entire query so...

Comment: it's not working..it's showing error like this:--You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.*, `mc`.`title` AS `cat1 FROM products_details pd INNER JOIN master_category mc' at line 2

SELECT * FROM `SELECT` `pd`.*, `mc`.`title` AS `cat1 FROM products_details pd INNER JOIN master_category mc ON pd`.`product_category = mc`.`id WHERE pd`.`status != 2 ORDER BY pd`.`product_name; ORDER BY product_name desc LIMIT 0`, 10

Answer (score 0):

Your order by clause must be after where condition.
Put it like below:-

```
    SELECT 
        products_details.*, master_category.title as cat1 
    FROM  
        products_details 
    JOIN 
        master_category ON products_details.product_category = master_category.id 
    WHERE
        1 = 1  AND products_details.status != 2
    ORDER BY 
        products_details.product_name;
```

Comment: Some *indentation* would make this query so much more readable ...